# C processor error for conio.h

Tags: c, macos, conio

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h" 
#include "stdlib.h"

#define RANGE(i, min, max) (i<min) || (i>max) ? 1: 0

int main (void )
{
    int r;
    do
    {
        do{
            r=rand();
        } while (RANGE(r, 1, 100));
        printf("%d", r);
    }
    while (!kbhit());
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this programme I find the following error:

> conio.h: No such file or directory

If delete `#include "conio.h"` then I find the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_kbhit", referenced from:
>         _main in cckd1NC4.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I solve this problem? What are reason behind these? Would you please tell me?

Comment: What is your target platform?

Comment: Why are you including `"conio.h"` instead of `<conio.h>`?  Ditto for `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Using `#include "conio.h"` rather than `#include <conio.h>` implies that you are supplying the header file rather than it being part of your compiler's libs. Are you supplying the header file?

Comment: Try changing to `#include <stdio.h> #include <conio.h> #include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: There is never a need for `X ? 1: 0` when `X` is already a boolean.

Comment: # include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  I have used this but not work. I did not supply any header file. But I does not work. I am running in Mac OS X.

Comment: @Kabir conio.h is primarly available on windows, not on OSX

Comment: side note: you should avoid defining RANGE() in this way: if you call RANGE(sideEffectFunction(), 1, 0) it will be expanded to tweo calls to that function.

Comment: "not work" is not an error message natively produced by C (or any other programming language, for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C #include `<lib.h>` is different to #include "lib.h". The first searches for the header files in the systems include path, and the second in the files include path

Answer (score 3):

the double quotes in `#include "something.h"` means the file `something.h` is present in the current directory ie where the source file is located. Where as the <> symbols in `#include <something.h>` means that something.h is present in the standarad library folder ie for example the `/usr/include` folder.
conio.h is a part of the standarad library so you need to use the <> symbols instead of the double quotes.
The error you are seeing is because the linker is not able to find the function definition of `kbhit()` to link with your code to make the binary/executable.

Comment: # include <stdio.h> #include <conio.h> #include <stdlib.h> I have used this but not work. I did not supply any header file. But I does not work. I am running in Mac OS X.

Comment: you should check your environment (C_INCLUDE path) or your -I parameters to the compiler

Comment: How do u compile?...Which compiler u use? Can you paste the command you use for compiling...As Peter said, you can use the -I parameter in gcc for specifying the include path

Comment: Actually, while double quotes are **poor form** here, they will work.  `#include "foo"` searches the current directory first, then the system directories.  `#include <foo>` searches **only** the system directories.

Comment: (Or, at least they would work if `conio.h` existed anywhere anymore.)

Answer (score 3):

`conio.h` is an old DOS header, almost never used anymore. The same functionality is now in `curses.h`. Make sure that curses (or ncurses) is installed  on your machine, and try

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <curses.h>
```

For what it's worth, `RANGE` is defined with far too few parenthases;

```
#define RANGE(i, min, max) (i<min) || (i>max) ? 1: 0
```

Would have problems with something like

```
 if(!RANGE(i, 100 200))
```

Which would become (parens added for clarity)

```
(!(i<100)) || (i>200)
```

Which isn't what you want. Define it instead as

```
#define RANGE(i, min, max) (((i)<(min)) || ((i)>(max)))
```

And, read up on [Macro Pitfalls](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html).